# How to upload a file and return JSON response in same click

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, web-development-server

My code for upload in views.py is

```
def upload(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['document']
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        uploaded_file.name = timestr+"_"+uploaded_file.name
        name = fs.save(uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file)
        context['url'] = fs.url(name)

    return render(request, 'upload.html', context)
```

And my HTML webpage looks like this: 
[image]

I am building an API and want to return JSON response when a user clicks on the upload button after choosing their file. I am using Django and new to web development.

Comment: So where are you having problems?

Comment: you can send your json in context which is optional parameter ...like this...render(request, template_name, context=None, content_type=None, status=None, using=None)[source]

Comment: You might want to add an different `return` at the bottom of the `if` block.

Comment: @KlausD. 
Thank you. I guess this is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You can return JSON response in three different ways in [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/).

1. [HttpResponse()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects)

```py
# using pure Django
from django.http import HttpResponse
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(context), content_type="application/json")
```

2. [JsonResponse()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects)

```
# using pure Django
from django.http import JsonResponse
return JsonResponse(context)
```

3. [Response()](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/#response)

```py
# using Django Rest Framework
from rest_framework.response import Response
return Response(context)
```